# Angular 2 @ngrx/redux store all strings (actions) to create a log

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have been thinking of ways that I could maintain a log of all the action strings that get executed by all my reducers. Firstly, it makes sense that this function could break the read only state of redux because this log would live outside of the application and shouldn't be used in going backwards in state. I figured a service would be ideal for this because they're inject-able and singletons. How would I go about injecting a service into my reducers or somehow saving the action strings to an array?

Here is an example reducer for my nav: How would I inject a service into this?

```
import * as Layout from '../_actions/layout.actions';

export interface State
{ 
    sideNavVisualState: boolean;
    sideNavWidthPx: number;
    sideNavMarginLeftPx: number;
}

const initialState: State = {
    sideNavVisualState: false,
    sideNavMarginLeftPx: 0,
    sideNavWidthPx: 0
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: Layout.Actions): State
{ 
    switch (action.type)
    { 
        case Layout.OPEN_NAV:
            return {
                sideNavVisualState: true,
                sideNavWidthPx: 250,
                sideNavMarginLeftPx: 250
            } as State;
        case Layout.CLOSE_NAV:
            return {
                sideNavVisualState: false,
                sideNavWidthPx: 0,
                sideNavMarginLeftPx: 0
            } as State;
        default:
            return state;    
    }
}

export const getSideNav = (state: State) => state;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject something in the reducer, but what you can do is the following:

1. Create a logging-service
2. Inject `Actions` from ngrx (`import {Actions} from "@ngrx/effects";`)
3. Subscribe to `Actions` and log them(or the `type`) to anywhere you want

So something like this:

```
import {Actions} from "@ngrx/effects";
// ...other imports

@Injectable()
export class YourLoggerService {
    public logAllActions$ = this.actions$
        .map(action => action.type)
        .do(actionType => /* ...some logging logic... */);

    constructor(private actions$: Actions) {
        this.logAllActions$.subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did to log actions to a dedicated service, using a `filter()` on the `actions$` to avoid logging everything – kind of like a negated `ofType()`

Answer (score 0):

ngrx already give you that by design. You want something else to happen when your action gets dispatched beside just pure function changing state (reducer)?

Why not just subscribe to same action in effects and do logging there?

**[UPDATE]**

And, of course, do injection vice versa: instead of injecting actions to services (what would you try to do that way, new effects implementation?) - why not inject logging service into effects?

**[UPDATE]**

ngrx store works like this:

1. You have reducers which are pure functions, meaning, they create no side effects. All they do is update the state. (take word 'update' with grain of salt especially if you mix ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and Immutables into story). Reducers are subscribed only to actions that should change state. For example, Load_Something_From_Server_FINISHED (meaning, you've got response from server). Within that actions payload you will/should have data from server and that is what your reducer will update state with.
2. You have side effect which also listen for actions but only those that initiate something with side effects, for example, ajax requests. So, effects listen to actions like Load_Something_From_Server_STARTREQUEST (and here, from effects, you call service that sends actual http request). When response comes back, you dispatch Load_Something_From_Server_FINISHED action (which reducer listens to) with data from server (data sent in action payload).
3. When you think about logging, its side effect by default. So, whenever some action was dispatched and reducer reacted to it (updated state), you also want to have that saved somewhere. Nothing prevents you to have both, effects and reducer to listen for same action as long as you use them for what they are meant for: reducer for updating state, effects for side effects.

This means, when your action is dispatched, your reducer should listen to it to update state and your effects to save to log.

Comment: I have never used effects and I am relatively new in terms of how to use Redux. Can you show a really basic example?

Comment: i've been in exactly the same situation a few months ago. I was completely lost with nrgx concept. What helped me most was the overall, global picture explained. For that reason, i will not post any code, you will find plenty of examples on net. Instead, i will try to give a bit more explanation about overall picture. Hope it will help. (i've updated my answer)